# I'm trying to display my questions after I have filtered them from a key that is an difficulty in my Array

Tags: javascript, html

There is a total of 30 questions in the array divided into 3 categories easy, medium and hard. Currently, the last 9 questions are showing the difficult questions when their box is checked and the quiz is started. the first question always shows the HTML placeholder that is in my index.html. Wondering if anyone can have a look at it to see where I am going wrong. If you need any more information let me know.

```
let pickDifficulty = () => {
if (easyDifficulty.checked) {
difficultyLevel = "easy";
} else if (mediumDifficulty.checked) {
difficultyLevel = "medium";
} else if (hardDifficulty.checked) {
difficultyLevel = "hard";
}
};

function displayQuestion(quizQuestion, quiz) {
quizQuestion.querySelector("#question").innerText = quiz.question;
quizQuestion.querySelector("#a-answer").innerText = quiz.a;
quizQuestion.querySelector("#b-answer").innerText = quiz.b;
quizQuestion.querySelector("#c-answer").innerText = quiz.c;
quizQuestion.querySelector("#d-answer").innerText = quiz.d;
}

difficulty.addEventListener("change",() => {
pickDifficulty();
const filteredQuestions = questions.filter(
(question) => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel);
},true);

function nextQuestion() {

if (questionCounter >= maxQuestion) {
endQuiz();
} else {
increaseQuestionCounter();
const quiztemplate = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz");
const quizparent = quiztemplate[0].parentNode;
quiztemplate.forEach((qq) => quizparent.removeChild(qq));
const quizquestion = quizparent.appendChild(quiztemplate[0].cloneNode(true));
const filteredQuestions = questions.filter(
(question) => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel);
const randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredQuestions.length);
displayQuestion(quizquestion, filteredQuestions[randomQuestion]);
}


<div id="difficulty" class="center">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff" value="easy">
        <label for="easy-diff">Easy</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff" value="medium">
        <label for="medium-diff">Medium</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff" value="hard">
        <label for="hard-diff">Hard</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="question-holder" class="hide">
<div id="question-counter"></div>
<div id="score-counter"></div>
<p id="post"></p>
<div class="quiz">
<p id="question">Question placement</p>
<ul>
    <li><label for="a" id="a-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="a" class="answer"></li>
    <li><label for="b" id="b-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="b" class="answer"></li>
    <li><label for="c" id="c-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="c" class="answer"></li>
    <li><label for="d" id="d-answer">possible answer</label><input type="radio" name="answer" id="d" class="answer"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button id="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

```
 startButton.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
 submitBtn.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out just add this to the event listener for my difficulty.

```
difficulty.addEventListener("change",() => {
pickDifficulty();
const filteredQuestions = questions.filter(
(question) => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel);
const randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredQuestions.length);
const quiztemplate = document.querySelectorAll(".quiz");
const quizparent = quiztemplate[0].parentNode;
quiztemplate.forEach((qq) => quizparent.removeChild(qq));
let quizQuestion = quizparent.appendChild(
  quiztemplate[0].cloneNode(true));
displayQuestion(quizQuestion, filteredQuestions[randomQuestion]);
},true);
```